# Trees using hair system are flickering after rendering

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, particles, sheepit

Using Blender 3.6, I created a landscape that has trees scattered using Blender's hair system.

After rendering out the scene animation, the trees are flickering. The children of the particle are same both in viewport and render. I tried unchecking the sequencer solution but still has the same issue after rendering.

In all attempts I rendered the file in Sheepit renderfarm.

[Blendfile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JQTqZcao98lyi2pwxiy0w8teKpBru3rJ/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the rendered result:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IVfB4gjuUvdyLj8wQfQ8plDp_Dwx_Yn-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: With Sheepit I remember also some crazy glitches, but before we will vote to close as off topic (if the reason is renderfarm you should ask there) ... Try to ... bake particle cache ... Render part of anim sequence (even with low-res) on your machine ... Try render without GPU (if issue still persists), just CPU.

Comment: It's not related to Sheepit. I've just rendered low-res 100 frames in Cycles and it glitches for some reason as shown in your video. In EEVEE, only the bottom left tree flickers. (Blender 4.0.2). The particles are static, nothing to bake.